# can not print passed structure

Tags: c, struct

Hi i want to pass an array of struct to a method than print the values of it but when i try that it only print zeros , note the main working well the problem is in max method :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct rectangle {
    float length;
    float width;
};

void max (struct rectangle * a, int size){
  printf("the test %d \n", (*a).width);
  int i;
  for(i=0; i<size; i++){
    printf("the test %d \n", a[i].width);
  }
}    


void main()
{
   printf("enter the size of both arrays \n");
   int x ;
   scanf("%d",&x);

   struct rectangle* r ;
   r =  malloc(x*sizeof(struct rectangle));
   int j ;
   for (j = 0 ; j < x ; j++){
     printf("enter rectangle length \n");
     scanf("%f",&r[j].length);
     printf("enter rectangle width \n");
     scanf("%f",&r[j].width);
   }

   for (j = 0 ; j < x ; j++){
     printf("  %f\n",r[j].length);
     printf("  %f\n",r[j].width);
   }
   max(r,x)

}
```

but when i try to run it it crashes .

Comment: `a = a+i` would cause problems because you would shift too much. Change it to `a++`:)

Comment: Suggestion: Instead of `**a` it would be easier to understand and maintain if you used array subscripting instead: `a[i]->width` for example.

Comment: Take out the line `a = a+i;` entirely, and change `(**a)` to `(*a)[i]`

Comment: It'd be better to just pass `r` to your function, rather than `&r`  (and redesign the function accordingly)

Comment: @tkellehe `a++` is not the right solution, that will lead to accessing unallocated memory.  `(*a)++` would work once, but trash `r` inside `main`.

Comment: You're making life hard for yourself by passing a pointer to a pointer to the `max` function.  It would be sufficient, and much more conventional, just to pass a pointer to the function.  Then you can increment safely through the array (not going through the list in quadratic progression as you are with `a = a + i;` — maybe you intended to write `a = a + 1;` but that is more often written `a++;` in C.  When you see stars and dots and parentheses, you should shoot arrows at it.  That is, `(*ptr).member` should be written `ptr->member`.

Comment: i changed the question just to explain to u my real problem

Comment: @user5277934 : in your latest code, you should use `max(r,x)` instead of `max(&r,x)` right?

Comment: @GNKeshava the same problem

Comment: @M.M True. I didn't necessarily check what `a` was just that `a = a+i` was really bad in that for loop:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are passing pointer to a pointer to structure, but in your function `max`, you are trying to access it as a structure pointer.

Use `max(r,x)` instead of `max(&r,x)`.

Edit :

Also, in `max` function:

```
printf("the test %f \n", a[i].width); // use %f instead of %d
```

Or if you really want them to print as `%d`, use following way:

```
printf("the test %d \n", (int)a[i].width); // use %d, and typecast float to int
```

Comment: i have a test after 3 hours but i don't know how to solve this, please help.

Comment: @user5277934 still crashing?

Comment: not crashing it dose not display the values it display 0 in max method

Comment: i am using windows 10 maybe it is the problem

Comment: @user5277934 , by the way, in function `max` , you are printing `%d`. try with `%f`

Answer (score 0):

Inside `max` you are attempting to print `float` values with `%d` format specifier. This will not work properly. `printf` formaty specifier for `float` values is `%f`, not `%d`.

Inside `main` you properly used `%f`. Why did you suddenly switch to `%d` in `max`?